# Range Data annotation attribute

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my project user form contain `SSN(Social Security Number)` field for that I have used javascript to format the textbox value into SSN format.

The issue is that I have used Range Data annotation attribute and when my textbox contains a formatted value like `132-456-789` it shows the data annotation error message ‘'DINTEGERC' must be within -2147483648 and 2147483647’.

So please let me know how can make Range Data annotation attribute to be work with above-given value.

Following is a definition of the field.

```
[Range(-2147483648, 2147483647, ErrorMessage="\'DINTEGERC\' must be within -2147483648 and 2147483647.")]
public System.Nullable<int> DINTEGERC{get;set;}//;
```

And textbox value: 123-456-789 will not work.

Comment: A value or `132-456-789` cannot possibly bind to a property which is `int`. The property must be `string` (and the `[Range]` attribute makes no sense)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `RangeAttribute` for formatted numeric value, since hyphens are not counted as numeric. Formatted SSN value must use `string` property inside model class by applying `RegularExpressionAttribute` annotation attribute as in example below.

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid SSN"]
public string SSN { get; set; }
```

If you want to accept either fully numeric or formatted values in textbox, the `RegularExpressionAttribute` should be changed to this:

```
[RegularExpression(@"^\d{9}|\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{3}$", ErrorMessage = "Invalid SSN"]
public string SSN { get; set; }
```

**Note:** As in DBA perspective, numeric data types such as `int` you're currently using should only used for calculated numbers, hence `string` data type is preferred.